# Mint Cinnamon shows login screen but not desktop

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, lightdm

Yesterday I updated my computer using apt and walked away to let it run. I ended up being away from it for a few hours. When I got back I saw that it was done, so I closed the terminal and shut the system down. When I turned it back on later, it got to the login screen but never showed the desktop. Only a black screen with a cursor. I switched to tty1 and that was working normally except apt would not update and I couldn't connect to wifi. I tried googling for solutions and ran `journalctl -xe` which showed both the network manager and lightdm trying to start and failing.

Here is a list of the packages apt upgraded before this issue started

```
fdisk:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.6)
uuid-runtime:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libfdisk1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
gnupg-utils:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
python-samba:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-117.118, 4.15.0-118.119)
gpg-wks-client:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
geogebra-classic:amd64 (6.0.604.0-202009091124, 6.0.606.0-202009222237)
gnupg-l10n:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.15-1, 0.4.15-1ubuntu0.1)
libproxy1v5:i386 (0.4.15-1, 0.4.15-1ubuntu0.1)
finalrd:amd64 (3~ubuntu18.04.0, 6~ubuntu18.04.1)
libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
libmount1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libmount1:i386 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
samba:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.15-1, 0.4.15-1ubuntu0.1)
samba-dsdb-modules:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
gpg-wks-server:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
util-linux:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
gpg:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
cifs-utils:amd64 (2:6.8-1ubuntu1, 2:6.8-1ubuntu1.1)
dirmngr:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
mount:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
libblkid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libblkid1:i386 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
busybox-static:amd64 (1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2, 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3)
libproxy-tools:amd64 (0.4.15-1, 0.4.15-1ubuntu0.1)
samba-common:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
firefox-locale-en:amd64 (80.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia, 81.0+linuxmint1+tricia)
libuuid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libuuid1:i386 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
mintdrivers:amd64 (1.4.1, 1.4.5)
gpgv:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.15-1, 0.4.15-1ubuntu0.1)
libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
rfkill:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
python-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
smbclient:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
samba-common-bin:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.19)
aptdaemon-data:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
bsdutils:amd64 (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6, 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7)
libssl1.0-dev:amd64 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3, 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.4)
gnupg2:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
code:amd64 (1.49.0-1599744551, 1.49.2-1600965325)
python3-aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.6)
firefox:amd64 (80.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia, 81.0+linuxmint1+tricia)
aptdaemon:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
gnupg:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64 (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.3, 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.4)
gpg-agent:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
gpgconf:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3, 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.4)
libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3, 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.4)
base-files:amd64 (19.0.1, 19.0.2)
gpgsm:amd64 (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2, 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.3)
busybox-initramfs:amd64 (1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2, 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3)
```

and [here is the output](https://pastebin.com/vBWVT193) of `journalctl -x --since='2020-09-30'`
(pastebin has an upload limit, so I had to trim the log down. I think I got the useful bits. A lot was pages of lightdm saying it couldn't open files.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Linux Mint 19 Tara, you are likely affected by the issue announced on [The Linux Mint Blog](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3969) and described in depth [on the forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=143&t=331605).

Summarizing the relevant forum post:

The issue concerns the base-file 19.0.2 update. The package content is empty and updating it results in creating the `/var/run directory`, which should be a symbolic link towards `/run`, preventing many system services from running correctly.

The solution:

1. boot in recovery mode:

   - Boot your computer
   - Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to force the boot menu to show up
   - Select Advanced options for Linux Mint 19
   - Select the "recovery mode" boot option
   - When the Recovery Menu appears, select "root - Drop to root shell prompt"
   - Press Enter
2. You will then be able to type commands. Run the following ones:

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   rm -rf /var/run
   ln -s /run /var/run
   ```
3. Reboot. Your computer should now boot normally and let you log in.
4. To completely fix the issue, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   wget linuxmint.com/tmp/base-files_19.0.1_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i base-files_19.0.1_all.deb
   ```